# Cannot deploy a minimal Application on my JBoss 7

Tags: jboss-eap-7, jboss-developer-studio

my goal is to call a REST-Webservice (on a local JBoss 7.1) via Postman and to write a pair of integers into a H2 database.

From the kitchensink example I imitated the necessary REST-classes:
The App class
    package rest;

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class App extends Application{

}
```

and the RestResource class following the paragraph transaction-scoped persistence context found on
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Developer+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-Applicationmanagedentitymanager:

```
package rest;

import javax.ejb.Stateful;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/pair")
@Stateful
public class RestResource {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;


    @POST
    public Pair writePair(Pair p) {
        em.persist(p);
        return p;
    }
}
```

And the Pair entity class:

```
package rest;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Pair {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private Integer number1;
    private Integer number2;
    public Pair() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Integer getNumber1() {
        return number1;
    }
    public void setNumber1(Integer number1) {
        this.number1 = number1;
    }
    public Integer getNumber2() {
        return number2;
    }
    public void setNumber2(Integer number2) {
        this.number2 = number2;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((number1 == null) ? 0 : number1.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((number2 == null) ? 0 : number2.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Pair other = (Pair) obj;
        if (number1 == null) {
            if (other.number1 != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!number1.equals(other.number1))
            return false;
        if (number2 == null) {
            if (other.number2 != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!number2.equals(other.number2))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    public Pair(Integer number1, Integer number2) {
        super();
        this.number1 = number1;
        this.number2 = number2;
    }
}
```

I do remember that I have to enter the same datasource name in the standalone.xml and the persistence.xml:

datasource paragraph standalone.xml:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:5.0">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
                    <driver>h2</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>sa</user-name>
                        <password>sa</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
```

persistence.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
   xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="primary">
    <class>rest.Pair</class>
      <!-- If you are running in a production environment, add a managed
         data source, this example data source is just for development and testing! -->
      <!-- The datasource is deployed as WEB-INF/kitchensink-jsp-quickstart-ds.xml, you
         can find it in the source at src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/kitchen-jsp-sinkquickstart-ds.xml -->
      <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS</jta-data-source>
      <properties>
         <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.jboss.heilmann</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <!-- Activate JBoss Product Maven repository.

        NOTE: Configuring the Maven repository in the pom.xml file is not a recommended procedure
        and is only done here to make it easier to use the quickstarts.

        For more information about how to configure Maven for your application,
        see the section entitled 'Use the Maven Repository'
        in the Development Guide for Red Hat JBoss Enterprise Application Platform located here:

        https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/jboss-enterprise-application-platform/
    -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-enterprise-maven-repository</id>
            <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>jboss-enterprise-maven-repository</id>
            <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <properties>
        <!-- Explicitly declaring the source encoding eliminates the following
            message: -->
        <!-- [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered
            resources, i.e. build is platform dependent! -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <!-- JBoss dependency versions -->

        <version.wildfly.maven.plugin>1.0.2.Final</version.wildfly.maven.plugin>

        <!-- Define the version of the JBoss BOMs we want to import to specify tested stacks. -->
        <version.jboss.bom.eap>7.0.0.GA</version.jboss.bom.eap>

        <!-- Other dependency versions -->
        <version.javax.servlet.jstl>1.2</version.javax.servlet.jstl>

        <!-- other plug-in versions -->
        <version.surefire.plugin>2.10</version.surefire.plugin>
        <version.war.plugin>2.1.1</version.war.plugin>

        <!-- maven-compiler-plugin -->
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- JBoss distributes a complete set of Java EE APIs including
                a Bill of Materials (BOM). A BOM specifies the versions of a "stack" (or
                a collection) of artifacts. We use this here so that we always get the correct
                versions of artifacts. Here we use the jboss-eap-javaee7-with-tools stack
                (you can read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE APIs, with some extras
                tools for your project, such as Arquillian for testing) -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-eap-javaee7-with-tools</artifactId>
                <version>${version.jboss.bom.eap}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- First declare the APIs we depend on and need for compilation.
            All of them are provided by JBoss EAP -->

        <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss EAP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the Common Annotations API (JSR-250), we use provided
            scope as the API is included in JBoss EAP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the Servlet API, we use provided scope as the API is
            included in JBoss EAP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the JAX-RS API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss EAP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_2.0_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the JPA API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss EAP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the EJB API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss EAP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL 1.2 or + -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${version.javax.servlet.jstl}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Bean Validation Implementation -->
        <!-- Provides portable constraints such as @Email -->
        <!-- Hibernate Validator is shipped in JBoss EAP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Now we declare any tools needed -->

        <!-- Annotation processor to generate the JPA metamodel classes
            for typesafe criteria queries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Needed for running tests (you may also use TestNG) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Optional, but highly recommended -->
        <!-- Arquillian allows you to test enterprise code such as EJBs and
            Transactional(JTA) JPA from JUnit/TestNG -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- Maven will append the version to the finalName (which is the
            name given to the generated WAR, and hence the context root) -->
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Java EE doesn't require web.xml, Maven needs to
                        catch up! -->
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- The WildFly plug-in deploys the WAR to a local JBoss EAP
                container -->
            <!-- To use, run: mvn package wildfly:deploy -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.wildfly.maven.plugin}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- The default profile skips all tests, though you can tune
                it to run just unit tests based on a custom pattern -->
            <!-- Separate profiles are provided for running all tests, including
                Arquillian tests that execute in the specified container -->
            <id>default</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.surefire.plugin}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <!-- An optional Arquillian testing profile that executes tests
                in your JBoss EAP instance -->
            <!-- This profile will start a new JBoss EAP instance, and execute
                the test, shutting it down when done -->
            <!-- Run with: mvn clean test -Parq-wildfly-managed -->
            <id>arq-wildfly-managed</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly.arquillian</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <!-- An optional Arquillian testing profile that executes tests
                in a remote JBoss EAP instance -->
            <!-- Run with: mvn clean test -Parq-wildfly-remote -->
            <id>arq-wildfly-remote</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly.arquillian</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be
                used when invoking mvn. -->
            <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization
                your app will need. -->
            <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the
                'deployments' folder. -->
            <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
            <id>openshift</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>deployments</outputDirectory>
                            <warName>ROOT</warName>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>




</project>
```

Finally, the console output after adding a beans.xml because of
[org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: Failed to parse "/WEB-INF/web.xml" at [6,1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443033/org-jboss-as-server-deployment-deploymentunitprocessingexception-failed-to-pars):

```
15:44:37,368 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found test.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called test.war.dodeploy
15:44:37,430 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "test.war" (runtime-name: "test.war")
15:44:38,298 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment test.war
15:44:38,352 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-6) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.3.5.Final-redhat-2
15:44:38,427 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'RestResource' in deployment unit 'deployment "test.war"' are as follows:

    java:global/test/RestResource!rest.RestResource
    java:app/test/RestResource!rest.RestResource
    java:module/RestResource!rest.RestResource
    java:global/test/RestResource
    java:app/test/RestResource
    java:module/RestResource

15:44:38,701 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-4) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Chakra' 8.2.8.Final-redhat-1
15:44:38,764 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "test.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:172)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEE0041: Component class rest.RestResource for component RestResource has errors: 
WFLYJPA0033: Can't find a persistence unit named primary in deployment "test.war"
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor$1.handle(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:157)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ClassDescriptionTraversal.run(ClassDescriptionTraversal.java:54)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.processClassConfigurations(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:186)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.deploy(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:143)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:165)
    ... 5 more

15:44:39,004 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 18) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
15:44:39,068 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "test.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"test.war\".INSTALL" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"test.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEE0041: Component class rest.RestResource for component RestResource has errors: 
WFLYJPA0033: Can't find a persistence unit named primary in deployment \"test.war\""},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"test.war\".beanmanager"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"test.war\".batch.artifact.factory is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"test.war\".beanmanager]",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"test.war\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"test.war\".beanmanager]"
    ]
}
15:44:39,155 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "test.war" (runtime-name : "test.war")
15:44:39,156 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".beanmanager (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".batch.artifact.factory, service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".weld.weldClassIntrospector] 
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "test.war"
```

Has anyone encountered the same problem?
How to deploy my project?
How to deal with the DeploymentUnitProcessingException?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could try `<class>rest.Pair</class>` in persistence.xml but otherwise I don't read German.

Comment: @K.Nicholas I added <class>rest.Pair</class> as you suggested. The devstudio gives me this error: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'jta-data-source'. One of '{"http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/
 persistence":class, "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence":exclude-unlisted-classes, "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence":shared-
 cache-mode, "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence":validation-mode, "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence":properties}' is expected.

Comment: Issue resolved. Inside <persistence-unit> <class> must not stand before <jta-data-source>. Still I have this: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"test.war\".beanmanager"]. But I do have a beans.xml. I dont understand :(

Answer (score 0):

You should specify your persistence unit name in the annoation. It should match the given name in the persistence.xml

```
public class RestResource {
  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "primary")
  private EntityManager em;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added the unit name the way you showed in your example. Unfortunately the problem persists. (DeploymentUnitProcessingException)

Answer (score 0):

In order for us to get English message, can you do the following:

- Double ckick on the server
- Click Open Launch Configuration
- in the VM Arguments tabs, add `-Duser.language=en` at then end
- Save and restart your server

Comment: Thank you for your help! I edited the original post. The console output should be in  English now.

Comment: I edited the original post. The console output is now displayed in English